# Undefined reference error in initializing a static pointer array of a class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, undefined-reference

This completely sums up the problem I am having right now:

```
class A{
public:
    int Avar;
    A(int Avar = 0){this->Avar = Avar;}
};

class B{
private:
    static A *AArray;
public:
    static void setAArray();
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}

void B::setAArray(){
    A *data;
    data = new A[10];
    AArray = data; // <- delete this line and the program complies
}
```

This piece of code says I have an undefined reference to 'B::AArray' and won't compile. How do I resolve this if I want a static pointer to an array of class A objects in class B?

Note: my class does not use multiple files currently and everything is under one .cc file

Edit: the question that is marked as duplicate as does not deal with a pointer or with an array of objects from another class. Tried solution from said post with no results.

Comment: The duplicate's accepted answer tells exactly what you need to do: provide a definition for `A::AArray`.

Comment: Trying to insert <code>A B::AArray;</code> or <code>A B::AArray = new A[10];</code> gives me multiple errors including "conflicting declaration" and "cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression". I can't seem to figure out a way to define B::AArray anywhere

Comment: You can define it anywhere at global scope under the definition of `B`, since you only have one cpp file. The syntax is simply `A *B::AArray;`.